# How do I connect mitmproxy to another proxy outside of my control?

Tags: python, proxy, mitmproxy, libmproxy

The process would be that the browser send a request to MITMproxy and then generate a request that gets sent to target proxy server which isn't controlled by us. The proxy server would send a response to MITMproxy which would then relay that response to the browser.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the -F flag to mitmproxy, which forwards proxy requests to an upstream server. Take a look at the docs here:

http://mitmproxy.org/doc/features/forwardproxy.html

Answer (score 17):

I was able to achieve what you ask with the following. You need to enable the upstream mode and upstream auth (in case you have some username/password for your proxy):

```
mitmproxy --mode upstream:https://HOSTNAME:PORT --upstream-auth USER:PASSWORD
```

Then you can check it's working with a simple `curl`:

```
curl -x http://localhost:8080 -k https://api.ipify.org/
```

This will forward your request to `mitmproxy` which will forward it to your other proxy.

Hope it helps!

Comment: FYI for others, most of the other answers seem to be for very old versions of mitmproxy. For anything recent (v3+), this `--mode upstream:` option is the way it's done. See https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-options/

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to do this not from the script, you can change the upstream server with get_upstream_server from server.config see [mitmproxy config] (https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/42d4a2fae96b8b4ba35d3a88e20f278d79a0ccc6/libmproxy/proxy.py). For example:

```
self.server.config.get_upstream_server = proxy.ConstUpstreamServerResolver(cmdline.parser_server_spec("http://upstreamserver:port"))
```

Comment: how do I use upstream server with script?

Comment: if u want to solve this via addons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72094131/11239018

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the `-U` option:

```
command-line    -U http://hostname[:port]
```

source: http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/features/upstreamproxy.html