# How to make a network request inside a Mitmproxy addon

Tags: mitmproxy

Let's say I have an addon that modifies a response from specific endpoints, like the one provided in the documentation example: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/api/events.html#event-hooks

Within that `response` function I want to make an http(s) request to an unrelated endpoint. To make http(s) requests I use the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library. Problem is, if I specify nothing but the url in the requests get/post method, I get `ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname` error. After researching this I got the impression that the underlying `urllib3` library requires extra proxy information. But if I try to provide proxies object that looks like:

```py
proxies={
    'http': f'http://127.0.0.1:{port}',
    'https': f'https://127.0.0.1:{port}',
}
```

I get the following error instead: `requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<hostname>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: <endpoint> (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1114: The handshake operation timed out')))`

I assume that any request made inside addon scripts goes through mitmproxy itself, where it successfully dies. Hence, I was wondering how to properly make http requests within mitmproxy addons?

---

OS: Windows 10
Mitmproxy version: 6.0.2

Comment: If you want to make a request to an unrelated endpoint why do you want to let the request pass Mitmproxy? Wouldn't it make more sense to directly connect to the endpoint without any proxy?

Comment: I do not want to let the unrelated request pass mitmproxy. It just happens because the proxy is activated on system level, so all requests, by default, go through it.

Answer (score 2):

**Make a file Named: multiproxy.py**

```
from mitmproxy import http
from mitmproxy.connection import Server
from mitmproxy.net.server_spec import ServerSpec

class multiproxy:

    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0
        
    def request(self, flow) -> None:
        address = ("target-ip-2", [target-port-2])
        flow.server_conn = Server(flow.server_conn.address)
        flow.server_conn.via = ServerSpec("http", address)
        
addons = [multiproxy()]
```

**Run mitmproxy with this addon:**

```
./mitmproxy --set block_global=false --ssl-insecure -s multiproxy.py
```