# Using Mitmproxy to strip SSL in a proxy chain results in maxRedirects-error

Tags: http, ssl, squid, mitmproxy

I want to setup the following Infrastructure, however I have issues with MITMProxy.

`Client --https--> MITMproxy --http--> squid --https--> Internet`

So basically MITMproxy should get rid of the SSL-encryption, then I want to cache stuff and then use again an encrypted connection to the Internet.

However, I can't get MITMproxy to forward the plain http-traffic. According to [How to chain mitmproxies with usual proxy in middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69804844/how-to-chain-mitmproxies-with-usual-proxy-in-middle/69824418#69824418), I should set `flow.request.scheme` to  `"http"` and `flow.request.port` to `80`.

I use that addon, however, there seems to be an issue, because I get an `Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop` error when testing HTTPS-sites with Postman.

MITMProxy logs:

```
192.X.X.X:54321: client connect
192.X.X.X:54321: server connect localhost:3128 (127.0.0.1:3128)
192.X.X.X:54321: server connect localhost:3128 (127.0.0.1:3128)
192.X.X.X:54321: client disconnect
```

Squid logs:

```
289 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 5179 CONNECT xyz.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/85.214.X.X -
105 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 576 CONNECT xyz.com:80 - HIER_DIRECT/85.214.X.X -
```

Both example logs are repeated 10 times, until the `maxRedirects` error is thrown.

From my point of view MITMproxy tries to establish SSL-connections to port 80. Anyone has a clue how to change that? Any other ideas are appreciated as well.

PS: I am using MITMproxy's upstream mode, could this be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I figured out that the transparent mode was the issue. When using `mitmproxy` in normal mode, everything worked as expected with the following add-on:

```
class ForwardRequest:

    def request(self, flow):
        flow.request.scheme = 'http'
        flow.request.port = 80

addons = [
    ForwardRequest()
]
```

Still, I can't forward the unencrypted traffic to squid (as this requires `mitmproxy` in `upstream-mode` which again could be an issue).

EDIT:
There still seems to be an issue. Check the following log from squid. `Mitmproxy` was used in upstream mode and said script to strip HTTPS was running.

[image]

The first row represents a request to HTTP://facebook.com. Here, no striping is done and the request successfully is transmitted.

In the second & third row, a request to HTTPS://fac.... is performed. As can be seen, squid also sees a request to facebook:443, which should not be there according to my understanding...